# Windows XP: How to find the files with 2 characters only?

Tags: windows-xp, find

recently I found back door on my laptop. I t was generating many files with random names only 2-3 characters only. The most of them is empty.
How can I find files only with 1 to 3 characters generated in the last 30 days?
Thanks Arman.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the search facility in Windows Explorer and use the '?' wildcard character.

Search for files names matching `?`, `??` and `???`. If the files have extensions, try `?.*`, `??.*` and `???.*`.

You can also specify the created date.

If your laptop has/had a backdoor, you really should be less concerned with the files on the system and more concerned with reinstalling your laptop, as it is the only sure way to close the back door and remove any root kits.

Comment: +1 nuke it from orbit. It's the only way to be sure. Don't expect anti-virus software to reliably remove all today's huge range of stealthy malware. 'Cos it won't. It'll just give you a nice false sense of security.

Comment: @Bryan: the method '??' does not find the files. but I can see in the windows/system32/ file named: 'hÏ'.

Comment: @Bryan: Well the double quotes "??" are solving the problem. Maybe it depends on locals? I am using the French  WinXP.

Comment: @bobince: Yes, I agree with the clean install, but  it is not always possible to reinstall all packages.

Comment: @Arman: Sorry, I didn't explain that very well, don't use any quotes as part of your search string. I've removed them from my answer and used highlighting instead.

Comment: @bryan: without double quotes it does samle as *, it finds all files. In my case it works only with double quotes:"??".

Comment: @Arman: See picture added for clarification. Strange how it doesn't work for you. Like you say, the difference *might* be down to the fact you are using the French version of WinXP?

Comment: @Bryan: Yes, you are right: with ??.??? works but I would like to find only files no extension, and without "dot" the ?? is finding all files. could you please try in your system ?? only, what is the output? You can see the result of my search: http://picasaweb.google.de/lh/photo/UDoPqQmDwrFXXIoJRk2q7w?feat=directlink

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misunderstood you. Yes my system behaves exactly the same as yours. I also need the double quotes when searching for the files without an extension.

Answer (score 2):

I think that this would work:

```
C:\>dir /s/b ???
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably easier to find empty files generated in the last 30 days.

Go to `Start` menu - `Search`

Click `When was it modified` select `Past month` or manually pick the dates.

Click `What size is it` select `Specify size` `at most` `1`KB

Answer (score 0):

Using Powershell:

```
$date = get-date

$olddate = $date.adddays(-30)

get-childitem -path c:\ -Recurse | where-object {$_.basename.length -lt "4" -and $_.creationtime -gt $olddate}
```